# How to hide toast in specific condition?

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I have written some piece of code. which helps in copying coupon code into the clipboard. and when code gets copied. toast will be shown.

The problem which i am facing is in if else condition. i don't want to show toast in if condition. or can say when set clickable is false i don't want to show toast.

```
lbs1_copyCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11) {
                                        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                                        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", lbs1_copyCode.getText());
                                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code Copied to Clipboard",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {

                                        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                                        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", lbs1_copyCode.getText());
                                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code Copied to Clipboard",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            final String coupon_code = documentSnapshot.getString(LOOT_BOX_SPECIAL1_KEY_COUPON_CODE);
```

I dont want to show toast in this condition.

```
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(coupon_code)) {
                                lbs1_couponCode.setText("NOT REQUIRED");
                                lbs1_couponCode.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                lbs1_couponCode.setClickable(false);

                            }
```

want to show toast in this condition

```
else {
                                    lbs1_couponCode.setText(coupon_code);
                                    lbs1_couponCode.setClickable(true);
                                    lbs1_couponCode.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#308fe9"));
                                }
```

Answer (score 1):

try creating the toast earlier in the onCreate method like this

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code Copied to Clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

and then whenever you want to show it you can simply call this

```
toast.show();
```

and to cancel/hide

```
toast.cancel();
```